# How do I use Mac OS aliases in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: macos, sublimetext3, alias, sublimetext, hardlink

I want to open the tree of folders which contains any code on my Mac in Sublime 3. Something like this:

[image: example]

But I don't have all of it in one folder, and it isn't convenient enough to open many folders in Sublime every time I close the app. So I have created 'aliases' (via Finder) to my folders and put them to one (folder), which i want to open with Sublime.

That didn't work out. Sublime opens these aliases as hex code. While ordinary folders open well.

[image: example]

So the main question: is there a way to make this work as I thought via preferences, or any plugin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use symbolic links instead by opening Terminal and using `ln -s <SOURCE> <ALIAS>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep any number of folders you want collected in one place by using [projects](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/file_management/file_management.html#projects). Simply drag the folders you want, in the order you want, into the sidebar. Then, select **`Project -> Save Project As...`** and save the file anywhere you want with the `.sublime-project` extension. While you're at it, make sure you have

```js
"hot_exit": true
```

in your user settings, as this enables you to close windows which have a project assigned to them, and all open files and unsaved changes are automatically preserved. When you next open the project, everything will be the same.